# Why is my test leaking file descriptors?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, jenkins, surefire

I'm using JUnit and Selenium2 to test my application. I execute the tests using Maven with the surefire plugin running in Jenkins. The test where fine some weeks and I added more and more tests and now the tests fails with this message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test (default-test) on project guitest: Failure or timeout
...
Process leaked file descriptors
```

I first thought I'm just leave files open in my code, for example when taking screenshots using the WebDriver (and apache commons IO to copy them):

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
File destFile = new File(...);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
```

But the problem persists even after removing the screenshot recording.

Do you guys have any pointers what's wrong here and/or how to tackle this problem?

**EDIT:**

I've implemented a WebdriverPool, to reuse WebDrivers / browser instances. I use a shutdown hook to close all open instances when the test has finished:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (WebDriver driver : drivers.values())
            driver.close();

        if (!driversInUse.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("There are still drivers in use (" + driversInUse.size() + ")");
    }
});
```

Might this be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have all your Input and OutputStreams in try-finally blocks (or in autocloseable blocks as of Java 7)? `SomeStream s; try { s = new SomeStream(); } finally { s.close(); }`

Comment: Yes, I don't use any streams in my test beside the copyFile method mentioned above. And this looks good.

Comment: Are you running this on linux? Have you checked your "ulimit"s?

Comment: No, it's a Windows 7 box

Comment: Does any test (even a blank one that only opens and closes the browser) leak the descriptors? Or any specific test? Selenium uses logging, maybe that's broken. What Selenium version do you use?

Comment: try using <forkMode>pertest</forkMode> in surefire plugin to narrow down the offending test case.

Comment: @Kal: I gave it a try with forkMode: pertest and the error did not occur. I already tried it three times and the test is not failing anymore.

Comment: This actually does not fix the problem, but should at least get it working. Only downfall is that it can take up longer to execute tests. But considering you are running Selenium tests, I am sure your tests are going to be already slow..

Comment: @Kal the forkMode: pertest creates a new WebDriverPool for each and every test. In that pool, I use a shutdownhook. Might that be the problem? See my edited question.

Comment: @TimBüthe Do you mean that you are still seeing leaked file descriptors? Your code will execute when the process terminates and with forkMod pertest it will execute for every test and will make it really slow. I am not sure I get your question though.

Comment: @TimBüthe Seems like a possible answer. Remove the hook and try to call it manually after the tests (or in the last test) to see what happens...